# Fixing vs Hiding "Undefined Variable" Errors in PHP

Tags: php

Depending on which error reporting I set, my web app either works or displays a ton of errors. I was under the impression I didn't need to initiate variables in PHP but setting the second error reporting seems to require it. What is going here? Should I go through and initiate all my variables?

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

Comment: Related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/130143/34530

Comment: initiate a variable? Can you post a small code snippet of something that fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking about whether to suppress the warning for uninitialized variables, but the code you are posting suppresses **ALL** `E_NOTICE` warnings.  This is not quite the same thing, but it's as close as you can get directly to what you're asking; there is no way to suppress only uninitialized variable notices.

In a way, notices are possibly the most important warning/error messages of all because they point out potential [logic errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_error), which are among the most difficult to identify and fix.

Given your options:

1. Suppress **ALL** `E_NOTICE` warnings.
2. Fix all uninitialized variables in your code.

I would recommend going with #2.  It's more work upfront, but a well-timed `E_NOTICE` might just save you a whole mess of trouble one day.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is trying to help you by issuing warnings - it is a very good idea to take notice of them.

Your code may work but PHP is saying that you have not thought about something - like initialising a variable.

Personally I have as many warnings on as possible. We all make the occasional error or forget something. The interpreter is there to help you by making sure that it tells you these things. Use it to its fullest abilities.

Answer (score 0):

You will receive a `notice` error, if you reference an identifier before they were initialised.

For example:

```
echo $variable; // is referencing to $variable which is not set before
echo $arrayname['indexname'] // it is also referencing to indexname item of array,
// if not found it will index another notice error
```

So, make sure you declare an identifier/variable before you reference it on our code, and you will be safe.

Answer (score 0):

what you're running into is the difference between a warning and an error.  A warning means "this may not produce the output you suggest", an error means "this is not working right".  You can suppress warnings without issue if your application otherwise works correctly.  But if you get odd behavior, turning on E_STRICT warnings could lead you to the bug in your code.

For example, if you attempt to loop through an array, but it never produces any results, turning on E_STRICT warnings could alert you to the fact that the array isn't being initialized before you try to loop through it.

Generally speaking, you'll turn off E_STRICT warnings in a production environment.  And it's generally just good practice to make sure your variables are initialized before you use them.

Comment: I disagree - I do not turn it off - In my production environment when a notice/error is issued is logged to a file instead of being sent to the user. i.e. I like to know if the production environment is having problems but in development I prefer it is on the screen. The production environment can periodically check the log file for any other these messages,

Comment: @Ed Heal: An excellent compromise.